# Zymic PHPMyADmin login

Tags: php

I have a Zymic webhosting account. I have a wordpress blog on it, but for some reason I can't login to PHPMyAdmin with my database name and password? Is there something I am missing?

Comment: Contact support at Zymic.

Answer (score 1):

The reason this has been marked down, I suspect, is that any problems with phpmyadmin pre-installed on your hosting account should be brought to the attention of the web host. If you had a programming/development issue with or affecting phpmyadmin, that might be different

Comment: Looks like a comment, rather than an answer, for me.

Comment: It's both a comment and an answer -- the answer part is, "Contact support"